# Automatically update Glue Data Catalog after writing parquet to S3 using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

Is there a way to automatically update Glue Data Catalog (without having a separate crawler) after writing parquet files to S3 from PySpark?

The [awswrangler](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html) python package can do it by specifying `database` and `table` in the `s3.to_parquet()`. Is there an equivalent way to do it in PySpark?

Comment: should `saveAsTable` work?